# Why Is Beautiful Soup Only Giving Me the First Entry in a Website?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to get the headline, date, and author from the articles listed on the following website: https://coreyms.com/

This is the code that I have run

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import csv
source = requests.get('http://coreyms.com').text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

for match in soup.find_all('div',class_='site- 
container'):

    headline=match.main.header.h2.a.text
    print(headline)
    date=match.main.header.p.time.text
    print(date)
    author=match.main.header.p.span.a.span.text
    print(author)

    print()
```

When I run this code, however, I only get the information from the first item. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
match = soup.find_all('h2')
for i in match:
    print(i.text)
    print(i.nextSibling.nextSibling.find('time').text)
    print(i.nextSibling.nextSibling.find('span').text)
    print('====')
```

Output:

```
Python Threading Tutorial: Run Code Concurrently Using the Threading Module
September 12, 2019
Corey Schafer
====
Update (2019-09-03)
September 3, 2019
Corey Schafer
====
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Question: Why did you write nextSibling? I don't see that in the source code.

Comment: @Andrew - the target data items are set next to each other (like brother/sister, as it were), but two steps away (with irrelevant items stuck in the middle). To reach from `title` to `date` and `author` you need to take two steps sideways (that's why the BS method `nextSibling()` is used twice. BTW, don't forget to accept the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a faster method which is to select all article tags then in a loop over those use class selectors to get your desired info

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://coreyms.com/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for article in soup.select('article'):
    title = article.select_one('.entry-title-link').text
    date = article.select_one('.entry-time').text
    author = article.select_one('.entry-author-name').text
    print(title, date, author)
```